# Infinite Loop (Maximum update depth exceeded)

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am having a problem with an infinite loop. I'm new in React and Redux, but maybe my approach is not correct. In my component I call a dispatch function like this:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        setUserProfileData: (profileData) => {
            dispatch(setUserProfile(profileData.userById))
        },
        setUserPermissions:(userPermissionData)=>{
            dispatch(setUserApps(userPermissionData.getUserPermissions))
        },
        setCurrentUserPermissions:(currentUserPermissionData)=>{
            dispatch(setApplications(currentUserPermissionData.getUserApplication))
        }
    }
}
```

Then I call another sub component with a callback method:

```
<UserPermissions 
  userId={this.props.router.params.id}
  setUserPermissionCallback={this.props.setUserPermissions}
  setCurrentUserPermissionCallBack={this.props.setCurrentUserPermissions}/>
```

Data is stored in redux perfectly, but when I call `mapStateToProps` it creates an infinite loop for:

> currentUserApps:state.applications.currentUserApps

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return(
        {
              router :  state.router,
              currentUserApps:state.applications.currentUserApps
        }
    );
};
```

Can any one please explain why this happens and how to solve this?

Comment: You’ll need to show more of your code. May also help to create a minimal example on codepen or codesandbox that demonstrates the infinite loop.